# How to turn a colour entity into a colour directive?

Tags: color, curated-data, entity

I am not experienced with Wolfram Knowledgebase queries and working with entities.

What is the "correct" way to convert a colour entity into a colour directive?

Example:

```
ent = StarData["Sun", "Color"]
(* Entity["Color", {"RGB", {1., 0.96, 0.93}}] *)
```

I want to convert `ent` to `RGBColor[1., 0.96, 0.93]`.

Is there an API for this, or is the only way extracting the part of the `Entity` expression?

Somehow extracting directly "doesn't feel right", but I may be mistaken about how this is intended to be used.  It also isn't very convenient to extract directly because when working with such queries, sometimes `Missing[...]` is returned.  Missing values are gracefully handled by functions such as `EntityValue`, but I'd have to handle them myself if I extract directly.  An example is `list = StarData[EntityClass["Star", {EntityProperty["Star", "DistanceFromEarth"] -> TakeSmallest[50]}], "Color"]`, which has some missing value.   Now `EntityValue[list, "HSLValue"]` simply skips missing values without failing, while I would have to do extra work to handle them myself.

Overall, this question is about how these functions are intended to be used, and what is the most convenient way to use them when chaining multiple queries. Extracting with `Part` is obviously trivial.

Comment: `FromEntity[]` should do the trick.

Comment: @J.M. Excellent!  Answer? Or should I delete?

Comment: I'm using a phone right now, so I'm not sure if it'd have worked. Please feel free to write something if it did work. :)

Comment: @J.M. Yes, this is easily found in the documentation.  Yet I did spend time on it and I didn't find it.  I guess I should keep this in mind when closing beginners' questions as a "simple mistake".

Answer (score 8):

[`FromEntity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromEntity.html) and [`ToEntity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToEntity.html) can do the conversion.

```
FromEntity[StarData["Sirius", "Color"]]
(* RGBColor[0.73, 0.8, 1.] *)
```

Comment: Or you could hit it with a hammer: `RGBColor @@ ent[[-1, -1]]`

Answer (score 6):

`ent` is an Entity of `"Color"` you can investigate its properties.

```
EntityProperties["Color"]
```

Of the many properties the `"Value"` property (strangely it has `CommonName` "Wolfram Language") will return the RGB color you are seeking.

```
ent["Value"]
(* RGBColor[1., 0.96, 0.93] *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought I had tried `EntityValue[ent, EntityProperties[ent]]`.  I must have only tried specific properties then.